# Elasticsearch service shutdown because "Temporary file directory [...] does not exist [...]"

Tags: elasticsearch

On some clients, Elasticsearch (7.6x) service is not running.
Log shows:
[image]

note that I copied the picutre from https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-es-tmpdir-issue/216953
but basically I had the same exception in logs (not available anymore).

That occurs when `~AppData\Local\Temp\elasticsearch` does not exist.
I don't know why this folder does not exist sometimes, but I am very confused that, ES depends in a `temp` directory. This seems weird.

Answer (score 3):

Just found following:

*The service automatically configures a private temporary directory for use by Elasticsearch when it is running. This private temporary directory is configured as a sub-directory of the private temporary directory for the user running the installation. If the service will run under a different user, you can configure the location of the temporary directory that the service should use by setting the environment variable ES_TMPDIR to the preferred location before you execute the service installation.*

This indicates, that user for installing and consuming differ!

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/zip-windows.html

Comment: The main takeaway here is you must set the variable BEFORE you install the service.